# Looking for a simple audio playback library for C++

Tags: c++, windows, audio

I'm working on a simple audio player, which is going quite well, using Qt and everything. But I'm in need of a solid but simple Audio library. I don't need anything fancy such as 3D sound and what do I know what else these things got nowadays. I'm just looking for something simple and efficient.

A list of features I'm looking for:

1. Audio playback from files
2. .ogg, .mp3 and .flac should be supported at the very least.
3. Should be able to pause playback.
4. I am planning to use it in C++

See. Nothing huge or anything, but at the same time I am having a hard time finding something suitable. The platform I'm targeting is Windows 7.

Anyone out there that knows something that I might be looking for?

Comment: Hey, there is a lot of answers here, that look pretty good to me. Don't you want to pick one as the right answer?

Comment: Yes, it's been a while since I came here. Done now. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best possible choice in my opinion is the [BASS](http://www.un4seen.com/) audio library, which is not open source, but free for non-commercial use.

It is used by the AIMP2 audio player, which you can use to check the sound quality, natively supports a lot of formats including MP3 and OGG, and uses plugins to support even more, including FLAC.

Answer (score 3):

How about [libavcodec](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libavcodec) ? Its LGPL. I'm not sure about ogg >_<

Comment: This seems a good step in the right direction. Just too bad it also covers video stuff, ideally I am looking for just audio. Regardless, this comes closest to what I need right now.

Answer (score 1):

I have used [BASS](http://www.un4seen.com/bass.html) before from a Windows C++ program, and it is very simple to use - link the DLL and call a couple of methods to specify the file to play back.

It certainly handles MP3 playback from a file as that's what I was doing.

I wish I could verify OGG and Flac, but alas I'm behind a firewall that has the site blocked.

Comment: I had a look at BASS, but it didn't seem to support FLAC. Although with an extension it apparently can. It's an option, but I don't know, having to add functionality with extensions seems like hassle. I just want a library that doesn't involve too much effort. Let's see if anyone else comes with a gem.

Answer (score 0):

[Miles](http://www.radgametools.com/) is a good and commonly used audio library.

Comment: It better be considering it costs $4000 USD, which goes far over my budget of $0 USD.

Comment: hmm, they use to have a free license for non-commercial use, but I can't seem to locate it at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Came across a good answer to my own question via an answer of another. FFmpeg is almost exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks all.

Comment: Isn't this the parent project of libavcodec that Reno suggested?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest [Openframeworks](http://www.openframeworks.cc/) or use of the [rtAudio](http://www.music.mcgill.ca/~gary/rtaudio/) library - that openframeworks is using -  directly. Oh, and on the side: rtAudio has pretty much no license restrictions. ;-)
Correct me, if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I use a C++ encapsulation of [FFMPEG](http://www.ffmpeg.org/) : [FOBS](http://fobs.sourceforge.net/)
Easy to use and C++ :)

**EDIT:**

Fobs is no longer maintained. However you can use it as a starting point to make your own C++ encapsulation of FFMPEG.

Comment: Discontinued, unfortunately.

Comment: @DecvSolar: Unfortunately. I update my answer ...

Answer (score 0):

DirectShow is actually pretty easy to use, flexible, and comes with Windows. There are a million examples, and it can be as easy or as sophisticated as you need it to be. When I throw together something that needs to play MP3s, I use it. Note that you are targeting Windows 7, so you could consider using [Media Foundation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_Foundation) instead.